# Is my proof wrong for: $n^k \in O(2^n) \text{ for any constant } k$

Tags: solution-verification, algorithms, asymptotics, fake-proofs, analysis-of-algorithms

I tried to prove this the following way, but not sure if this is correct?

$n^k \leq c \cdot 2^n$

$\log_2(n^k) \leq \log_2(c \cdot 2^n)$

$\log_2(n^k) \leq \log_2(c) + \log_2(2^n)$

$\log_2(n^k) \leq \log_2(c) + n$

$\text{If } n = k, \text{ then } \log_2(k^k) \leq \log_2(c) + k$

$\text{If } c = k^k, \text{ then } \log_2(k^k) \leq \log_2(k^k) + k$

Comment: You were asked to prove that $[\forall k,\exists c, \exists M, \forall n\ge M, n^k\le c2^n]$, therefore the fact that for any given $k$ the inequality holds for $n=k$ and $c=k^k$ is irrelevant.

Comment: If you don't mind elaborating, does that mean after setting n = k, it is the end of the proof and I didn't need to set c = k^k?

Comment: It means that by setting $n=k$ you invalidate any chance of writing a proof.

Comment: Would you accept this argument from someone?  "Claim:  The function $f(x)=x+10$ always has prime outputs for $x$ natural.  Proof:  Well, with $x=1$ we have $f(1)=11$ which is prime, so we're right."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your proof is wrong.

By setting $n=k$, you're ignoring that the statement you were asked to prove is for any $n$ *and* for any $k$.

What you have proven is that any constant is asymptotically limited by $2^n$, not really interesting.